How to Create a Custom Page with a Modal in Filament 3 for Laravel 10?
I am migrating the back office of a project developed using classic Laravel 10 to Filament 3.
I have understood the CRUD system in Filament 3, and the documentation is quite clear. However, I have a page in my back office with a complex table that calls multiple models. This table is supposed to display the menus of an establishment over 7 days. For each day, there are 3 meals, and for each meal, there are several recipes/dishes with the number of servings.
It doesn't seem possible to use the standard Filament functions because it's not really a classic CRUD. Therefore, I decided to create a custom page, which seems to be the best solution since the page needs to call multiple models and has a very specific design with various manipulations (moving a menu from one day to another by drag-and-drop, moving a menu item similarly, adding guests, etc.).
My current problem is that I cannot create a modal that displays the content of a specific model. Here, it's about $recettemenu.
Another question: Is this the right direction to create a complex page?
Here's my setup:
I created my page, and I have the app/Filament/Pages/Menu.php file with the following content:
namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use App\Models\Recette;
use App\Models\RecettesMenu;
use Filament\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Pages\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Menu extends Page
{
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-document-text';
    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.menu';

    public $debutsemaine;
    public $finsemaine;
    public $dates = [];
    public $recettes = [];
    public $matinmidisoir;
    public $entreeplatdessert;
    public $allrecette = [];
    public $recette;

    public function mount(Request $request)
    {
        $next = $request->input('next');
        $last = $request->input('last');
        $datedebut = $request->input('datedebut');

        if (isset($next)) {
            $this->debutsemaine = Carbon::parse($next)->nextWeekday()->format('d-M-y');
            $this->finsemaine = Carbon::parse($this->debutsemaine)->nextWeekday()->endOfWeek()->format('d-M-y');
        } elseif (isset($last)) {
            $this->debutsemaine = Carbon::parse($last)->previous(Carbon::MONDAY)->format('d-M-y');
            $this->finsemaine = Carbon::parse($this->debutsemaine)->endOfWeek()->format('d-M-y');
        } elseif (isset($datedebut)) {
            $this->debutsemaine = Carbon::parse($datedebut)->format('d-M-y');
            $this->finsemaine = Carbon::parse($this->debutsemaine)->endOfWeek()->format('d-M-y');
        } else {
            $this->debutsemaine = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('d-M-y');
            $this->finsemaine = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('d-M-y');
        }

        $period = new CarbonPeriod(Carbon::parse($this->debutsemaine), 7);
        foreach ($period as $date) {
            $this->dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        $this->recettes = Recette::all()->pluck('nomrecette', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '')->toArray();
        $this->matinmidisoir = ['Midi', 'Gouter', 'Soir'];
        $this->entreeplatdessert = ['Entree' => 'Entree', 'Plat' => 'Plat', 'Dessert' => 'Dessert'];

        $this->allrecette = RecettesMenu::with('recette')
            ->whereDate('date', '>=', Carbon::parse($this->debutsemaine))
            ->whereDate('date', '<=', Carbon::parse($this->finsemaine))
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    }

    public function showmenuAction($recetteId = null): Action
    {
        return Action::make('showmenu')
            ->label('Voir le menu')
            ->modalHeading('Détails du Menu')
            ->modalContent(function () use ($recetteId) {
                $this->recette = Recette::where('id', $recetteId)->first();
                $recette = $this->recette; // Ensure the variable is defined correctly
                return view('filament.pages.modal-menu', compact('recette'));
            })
            ->form([
                TextInput::make('recetteId')
                    ->label('ID de la recette')
                    ->default($recetteId)
                    ->hidden(),
            ]);
    }
}

And on the other side, I have my Blade file in resources/views/filament/pages/menu.blade.php where I have a loop like this:
@foreach ($allrecette as $recettemenu)
    @if ($recettemenu['perioderepas'] == $period && $recettemenu['entreeplatdessert'] == $entreeplatdessertd2 && \Carbon\Carbon::parse($recettemenu['date'])->isSameDay(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)))
        <div class="">
            <a href="#" class="text-blue-600 hover:underline">
                {{ $recettemenu['recette']['nomrecette'] }}
            </a>
            {{ ($this->showmenuAction)(['recetteId' => '46']) }}

            <span id="prixrecette_{{ $recettemenu['id'] }}" class="{{ $period }}_{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('d-m-Y') }}">{{ $recettemenu['prixrecette'] }}€</span>
            <input type="text" id="nbpersonnerecette_{{ $recettemenu['id'] }}" name="nbpersonnerepas" class="align-middle border rounded w-1/6 h-3 p-1.5 text-[12px]" value="{{ $recettemenu['nbpersonne'] }}">
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach

How can I correctly create a modal that displays the content of a specific model (in this case, $recettemenu)?
Is creating a custom page the right approach for building a complex page with various models and specific design requirements?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

did u nd any solution to this

Do you mean like this? https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/5528
